# ACF visual wysiwyg field not displaying formatting

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My ACF WYSIWYG field is not displaying formatting on the front end once a post is published.

Screenshot of how it looks in wp admin:
[image]

But once this goes live it just goes into a mush of text without spacing. Strong tags seem to stay..
[image]

Using this to display the WYSIWYG acf field:

```
<?php (the_field('description')); ?>
```

Comment: Using: <?php the_field('description'); ?>

Not <?php (the_field('description')); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
the_field('description', false, false);
```

The third parameter is for format value. You may also check the documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: Doesnt work. 

Problem seems to be that it doesn't add formatting html. No <p> tags etc. Only <b> and <ul> seem to work...

Comment: Did you add any filter hooks for the_content?

Comment: No, but using understrap framework, so that might add something.

Comment: Try switching to some default theme and check whether it persists or not

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was a tinyMCE setting. For others tick this:

[image]

The job descriptions are now formatted at https://workfromhomejobs.me/remote-developer-jobs/